# Why doesn't TypeScript type guard 'in' narrows types to keyof types?

Tags: typescript, type-systems

Consider this code:

```
const obj = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
}

let possibleKey: string = 'a'

if (possibleKey in obj) console.log(obj[possibleKey])
```

When `possibleKey in obj` is true, we know that `possibleKey` has type `keyof typeof obj`, right? Why doesn't TypeScript type system detects that and narrows down `string` to that type? Instead, it says:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ a: number; b: number; }'.
```

Comment: "*When `possibleKey in obj` is true, we know that `possibleKey` has type `keyof typeof obj`, right?*" not exactly. `possibleKey` could be coming from the *prototype* of `obj`. Not sure if TS considers this an important distinction but it might, in which case `possibleKey` won't be a(n own) key of `obj`.

Comment: @VLAZ - That's okay, TypeScript considers prototypes supertypes (effectively). The same problem occurs with a `hasOwnProperty` check.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ah, good. I wasn't sure of that. It's likely a different problem, then.

Answer (score 8):

Per [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-the-in-operator):

> For a `n in x` expression, where `n` is a string literal or string
>   literal type and `x` is a union type, the “true” branch narrows to
>   types which have an optional or required property `n`, and the “false”
>   branch narrows to types which have an optional or missing property
>   `n`.

In other words, `n in x` narrows *`x`*, not `n`, and only for string literals or string literal types `in` union types. For that expression to work, you'd have to give the compiler more information, e.g. using a [*type assertion*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions):

```
if (possibleKey in obj) {
  console.log(obj[<keyof typeof obj>possibleKey]);
}
```

Comment: It's probably worth noting that `obj[<keyof typeof obj>possibleKey]` will have the type `number` in the OP's example because all properties of `obj` have number values, but if `obj` were (say) `{a: 1, b: "foo"}`, it would be `number|string`... So this gets you closer, and is useful in some places, but still may leave you with a further type check and assertion to do...

Comment: One [stated reason not to narrow `n`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18282#issuecomment-327636329) is that the `x` object might have properties not mentioned in `x`'s type (i.e., object types aren't [exact](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936)). This doesn't apply when `x`'s type is inferred from an object literal like `{a:1, b:2}` as in the question, though, but I guess they haven't wanted to special-case that.  A user-defined type guard with signature `<T extends object>(k: PropertyKey, o: T) => k is keyof T` might help here, if this is a common operation.

Comment: I think `x` is not narrowed either, because this also does not compile when `noImplicitAny` is active: `const n = { a: 1 }; let x = 'a'; if (x in n) n[x] = 2`

Comment: @AndréValenti that's because in that example `x` is implicitly `string`, not the string literal type `'a'`; if you make it `let x: 'a' = 'a';` or `const x = 'a';` the compiler is happier.

Comment: Yeah, but, in that case, I see no point in asserting `x in n`, since it will always be `true`, except if someone messed with the object during runtime.

Comment: @AndréValenti in that toy example, yes, but also e.g. `let x: 'a' | 'b' | 'c'; x = 'a';`. The point is `x` needs to have string literal type, or be a string literal.