# Typescript typeguard using "in" keyword, not working as expected for objects

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have object const which map to title of 3 pages on a dynamic route.

```
const ROUTES = {
  '1': 'Page 1',
  '2': 'Page 2',
  '3': 'Page 3',
} as const
```

I'm checking if the route param is one of these keys using,

```
const page = params.page
if (!page || !(page in ROUTES))
    return <Navigate to="/profile" replace />

page // <-- This is of type string instead of "1" | "2" | "3"
```

I've read that the `in` keyword can be used as a typeguard and I think I'm using it correctly here. But even after the conditional, the page variable is of type `string` and not `"1" | "2" | "3"`.

For now, I'm reassigning and casting it to a `typedPage` constant but I feel this is unnecessary and there has to be a way using just the typeguard.

Apologies if this is asked here before but I couldn't figure out the right keywords to find this.

Comment: I don't see a question here... I'm assuming it's "why is this happening"? And the answer is that it's a missing feature; checks like `k in o` can narrow `o` but not `k`.  The relevant feature request is at [ms/TS#43284](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43284); if that fully addresses the question then I'll write up an answer explaining; otherwise, what am I missing? (And it might help for you to [edit] the post to ask an explicit question)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't TypeScript type guard 'in' narrows types to keyof types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59628330/why-doesnt-typescript-type-guard-in-narrows-types-to-keyof-types)

Comment: You can have a custom typeguard `function isRoute(page: string): page is (keyof typeof ROUTES) {
  return page in ROUTES;
}` and then use it for type narrowing `if(isRoute(page)) console.log(ROUTES[page])`. Provided that you are sure nobody would pass `page = 'hasOwnProperty'` :)

Answer (score 0):

your code works as expected because this typescript code is transpiled into javascript at the end of the day.

So, you are checking if `page in ROUTES` in another words, if page is of value `"1"` and of type string, it is compared to the `ROUTES` prototype object and it does exists there as a string field.

what you need is create a new type `ROUTE_KEYS` of the `ROUTE` object keys and cast your page to that type.

working [TSplay here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBASgeQKoBUCiBlGBeGBvAKBmJgHIBGUmALjPAFNSAaIk0gJittKgHcRmrYqQDMXMlAAWAJ3qMCAXwIEoATwAO9GAAUAggHE0AfUSpMOGAGt6qkADMYazffjJ0GANxECoSLHUAhgDmWrgUpF6%20ECAANvQAdDEgQQAUgSEwARA6Bsam7gCUHkA)